# Inventory Adjustment - Before Record Load: Create - Set Item Sublist

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Can someone guide me on how I can set my line item on inventory adjustment module?
The idea was to set the line item based on the existing line of my sales order record.
The problem was, upon clicking the save button it returns a prompt message: **"You must enter at least one line item for this transaction."**
Here is my script used.

```
var cfrom_rec = record.load({type: cfrom_type,id: cfrom_id});
var ia_location = cfrom_rec.getValue('location');
var productionquantity = 'custcol_prod_quantity_1_entre';
var cfrom_line = cfrom_rec.getLineCount('item');
var linedisplay = 0;
for(var x=0; x<cfrom_line; x++){
    var item_type = cfrom_rec.getSublistValue('item','itemtype',x);
    log.debug('item_type',item_type);
    if(item_type== 'InvtPart'){
        var item_id = cfrom_rec.getSublistValue({sublistId : 'item',fieldId : 'item',line : x});
        newRecord.setSublistValue({
            sublistId : 'inventory',
            fieldId : 'item',
            line : linedisplay,
            value : item_id
        });
        newRecord.setSublistValue({
            sublistId : 'inventory',
            fieldId : 'location',
            line : linedisplay,
            value : ia_location
        });
        var adjustqty = parseFloat(cfrom_rec.getSublistValue({sublistId : 'item',fieldId : productionquantity,line : x}));
        if(adjustqty == ''){
            adjustqty = 0;
        }
        newRecord.setSublistValue({
            sublistId : 'inventory',
            fieldId : 'adjustqtyby',
            line : linedisplay,
            value : adjustqty
        });
        newRecord.setSublistValue({
            sublistId : 'inventory',
            fieldId : 'units',
            line : linedisplay,
            value : cfrom_rec.getSublistValue({sublistId : 'item',fieldId : 'units',line : x}),
        });
        newRecord.setSublistValue({
            sublistId : 'inventory',
            fieldId : 'custcol_hnd_skuline',
            line : linedisplay,
            value : cfrom_rec.getSublistValue({sublistId : 'item',fieldId : 'custcol_hnd_skuline',line : x}),
        });
        linedisplay++;
    }
}
```

Hoping someone can guide me on this. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify why you're trying to set a line on an inventory adjustment from a sales order record?

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends on if the "newRecord" is in dynamic mode or standard.  "newRecord.isDynamic" will return true or false, if you need to check via script.  The Record.setSublistValue(options) method is only for working with records in Standard mode.  If working with a record in dynamic mode, you will need select a line or insert a line, set the values, the commit that line.

```
newRecord.selectNewLine({
  sublistId: 'inventory'
});
newRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
  sublistId: 'inventory',
  fieldId: ____,
  value: ___,
  ignoreFieldChange: ____ //default is false = the field change and the secondary event is not ignored
});
newRecord.commitLine({
  sublistId: 'inventory'
});
```

For more information on standard vs dynamic, refer to Suite Answer id 73792.  For more information on setSublistValue method, refer to Suite Answer id 45396.

If you're already working with a record in standard mode, the only suggestion I have is to make sure you're setting all of the required fields in an order similar to how you would via the UI.